# Overlay div not appearing when select box is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table with select boxes in the table headers that filter the rows.  This is a large table, and filtering on a text column with long strings can take some time.  I'd like an overlay to appear while the filtering is going on and hide it when the filtering is done.

```js
$('#budget-table select').change(e => {

  $('#overlay').show()

  // get the selected options of all the filters at the top.
  const filters = $('#budget-table th select').find(':selected').map((ind, elt) => elt.innerText)

  $(`#budget-table tr`).each((trInd, trElt) => {
    if (trInd == 0) return true // skip the header row

    let showRow = true

    // If the filter is not 'All' and the cell value doesn't match the filter, hide the row.
    $(trElt).children().each((tdInd, tdElt) => {
      if (filters[tdInd] !== 'All' && filters[tdInd] !== tdElt.innerText) {
        showRow = false
        return false
      }
    })
    showRow ? $(trElt).show() : $(trElt).hide()
  })

  $('#overlay').hide()
})
```

```css
#overlay {
  background-color: #333;
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.6;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="project-list">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-rwd" id="budget-table">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <select class="filter-select" data-columnindex="0" id="filter-input-0">
          <option>Option 1</option>
          <option>Option 2</option>
          <option>...</option>
          <option>Option n</option>
        </select>
        <div>
          Territory
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>...several more filters with the same structure</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">...several hundred rows of table data</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="overlay"> </div>
```

The overlay isn't showing.  However, if I move `$('#overlay').show()` to after the outer `each()` function, the overlay *will* show.  What am I missing?

Comment: JS code that takes some time blocks the browser, try wrapping the .each and .hide code in `setTimeout(function() {` and `}, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

The `each` loop will run asynchronously. To wait for the loop to finish, make the `change` callback asynchronous and add `await` before the `each` loop.

```js
$('#budget-table select').change(async e => {

  $('#overlay').show()

  // get the selected options of all the filters at the top.
  const filters = $('#budget-table th select').find(':selected').map((ind, elt) => elt.innerText)

  $(`#budget-table tr`).each((trInd, trElt) => {
    if (trInd == 0) return true // skip the header row

    let showRow = true

    // If the filter is not 'All' and the cell value doesn't match the filter, hide the row.
    await $(trElt).children().each((tdInd, tdElt) => {
      if (filters[tdInd] !== 'All' && filters[tdInd] !== tdElt.innerText) {
        showRow = false
        return false
      }
    })
    showRow ? $(trElt).show() : $(trElt).hide()
  })

  // artificial delay
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500));

  $('#overlay').hide()
})
```

```css
#overlay {
  background-color: #333;
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.6;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="project-list">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-rwd" id="budget-table">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <select class="filter-select" data-columnindex="0" id="filter-input-0">
          <option>Option 1</option>
          <option>Option 2</option>
          <option>...</option>
          <option>Option n</option>
        </select>
        <div>
          Territory
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>...several more filters with the same structure</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">...several hundred rows of table data</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="overlay"> </div>
```